# Binary Tree Size function in Python

Tags: python, binary-tree

I have written a couple of functions to calculate size of binary tree. The first one (Function 1) works perfectly fine and is declared outside the class, it is not a member function of the class. However the second one which is the member function of the class is giving me weird results. I am confused! Any help would be appreciated.

```
Function 1
    def size(root):
        if root is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return size(root.left)+ 1+ size(root.right)


Function 2
    def size(self):
        if self.left is None or self.right is None:
              return 0
        else:
              return self.left.size()+1+self.right.size()
```

Comment: Your if statement conditions are not equivalent between the functions. Specifically the second function returns 0 if either left or right children don't exist. That's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if self.left is None or self.right is None:
```

if one of them is None, return 0

you need to at least get the size of the right + 1 if left is None

I think you need something like :

```
leftSize = self.left.size() if self.left else 0
rightSize = self.right.size() if self.right else 0
return leftSize + 1 + rightSize
```

I havent tried it.

Answer (score 2):

The second function is not accurate, for example

```
x = Tree()
x.left = Tree()
x.right = None
```

In the above example, `x.size()` would evaluate to zero, since you are considering either `left is None` or `right is None` to return 0 (which is trivially true for the above example). You need to tweak your logic.

```
def size(self):
    total = 1 #any instantiated object has a size of at least 1.
    if self.left is not None: #feel free to add additional validity checks, i.e. instanceof(Tree...)
        total += self.left.size()
    if self.right is not None:
        total += self.right.size()
    return total
```

Comment: Thanks! +1, Appreciate your help.